# Prevent the scheduler to do a context-switch in Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, scheduler

In Java: Is it possible to prevent the scheduler (Ubuntu) to do a context-switch on a specific part of a thread-code.

And if so, how?

Comment: It's not. What if the code never finished?

Comment: no.  pretty sure this is not possible in any general purpose operating system.  why do you think you want this?

Comment: You could yield before and hope.

Comment: So, what you _really_ want?

Comment: Thx. Thats some thing i think about too @ Jan Dvorak. just think about @ jtablborn: so you can gurant a System.out after got pased a acquire or somthing like this..

Comment: Would making the portion of your code atomic not enough? (i.e. no 2 threads can run that portion of your code simultaneously)

Answer (score 2):

You should go for a realtime thread:

http://jrate.sourceforge.net/api/stable/javax/realtime/RealtimeThread.html

and set its priority to the maximum level:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29

This way, once the realtime thread is started, it won't release the processor anymore.

More, the scheduler should be asked to behave like a (realtime) FIFO scheduler.

You have a setScheduler() method.

Comment: +1 That could work except you need a JVM which supports this and I only know of one, Java RTS, which is expensive and not maintained so well these days as it's not widely used.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to avoid context switching is use thread affinity, busy waiting and isolating the cpus (if the OS supports that)  Java doesn't support these so well but with the help of a little JNI/JNA it can be done.

[Thread Affinity library for Java](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/thread-affinity-library-for-java.html)

Note: There are NMI interrupts which cannot be prevented but usually don't have much impact.